# move_uploaded_file doesn't like tmp_name

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to achieve is a multiple image upload.
This should work yet it's not uploading and giving me an `Internal Server Error`. If I change `tmp_name` to `name` I don't get an error and my data tests run, but of course, no upload.

```
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage'.$i]['tmp_name'], $path .       
$image[$i]['name']);

if ($moveresult != TRUE){
   echo $_FILES['uploadimage'.$i]['name']. " was not uploaded <br/>";

//TEST STUFF
echo "Path & new filename = " . $path . $newFileName. "<br/>";
echo "Temp file name: " . $file_tmp . "<br/>";
echo "moveResult = " . $moveResult . "<br/>";
if ($db_conx == TRUE){
    echo "DB test: OK";
}
//END TEST STUFF

}else{
echo "moved file = " . $_FILES['uploadimage'.$i]['tmp_name']."&nbsp;" .$path.    
$newFileName. "has been uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Be sure to include the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" in your file upload form. This is often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `FcgidMaxRequestLen` in httpd.conf file

use something like

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 67108864
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go Dinesh... I just have to find it first. This is all pretty new to me.

Comment: Should I be able to access that via phpMyAdmin or do I need another approach?